# Recognizing a pattern using OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, pattern-matching

This my problem.

I have a symbol written in black in a white background. As an example assume my symbol is "Z". But it does not has to be a letter always.

Now i have image of this pattern stored.

Then i draw another pattern. image size will be same as the above. Then i input this new pattern to my program and i want to check whether it matches to the stored pattern.

Even if the new patten has a similar shape but different size, it should be matched to the stored image. Therefor pattern shape is the differentiating factor. Obviously rotated patter means a different pattern.

Is there a way to do this in opencv??

I tried using feature matching. But it did not work. I think i can use a classifier but i do not have a good knowledge on that.

Can some one help me??

Comment: Do you have a snippet of code showing what you have done so far?

Answer (score 7):

user2389323 - The short answer is yes, you can do what you described using OpenCV.  Pattern matching using image processing techniques is a major piece of OpenCV.  Here are some example conversations I have found dealing with this topic:

***[Edge Based Template Matching](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99457/Edge-Based-Template-Matching)*** (includes source downloads)
***[Template Matching and Slice Alignment](https://sites.google.com/site/qingzongtseng/template-matching-ij-plugin)***
***[Template Matching - Example code and tech description](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)***

I hope these links have something to help you.  They were not hard to find using *Pattern Matching using OpenCV* in Google :)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.

Actually i looked in to template matching also when i was searching for a method. But when the size is different, i thought it is not possible to use template matching for accurate result.

Comment: by th way, the first link leads to a page that is private.

Comment: @ErikAllik - Thanks, its link must have changed somehow since I first posted this.  I have removed it.

Comment: @user2389323, have you found a way to use template matching for differently sized images? I have a similar problem as you.